# how to fetch allkeys from dictionary which are kept inside the array

Tags: xcode

i want to fetch all keys from ditionary.But the problem is that these dictionary is in the array.
means i have a array 0,1,2,3
and inside 0 there are multiple dictionaries like {5,6,7,8,9} these 5,6,7,8 are the dictionaries in which data are kept.
so how can i achieve allkeys means {5,6,7,8,9}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like allways, with arrays in arrays, you could try .each.each
Here is a link to a tutorial about for each loops.
[KLICK ME](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-Foreachloopin.html)
Just put one loop on the outer array and one on the inner one!